# Getting rows from multiple table - PHP and loop

Tags: php, sql

I'm trying to search for all the parent category of child category from 2 tables

Sample database

```
table1                            table2
+------------+-------------+      +------------+-------------+
|Categ_name  |Categ_parent |      |Temp_name   |Temp_parent  |
+------------+-------------+      +------------+-------------+
|Items       |0            |      |Cookware    |Kitchen      |
|House       |Item         |      |Utensils    |Cookware     |
|Car         |Item         |      +------------+-------------+
|Kitchen     |House        |
|Living Room |House        |
|Appliance   |Living Room  |
+------------+-------------+
```

if I search for 'Utensils', hoping to get

Categories :

- Cookware
- Kitchen
- House
- Items

as a result but I'm a little confused with SQL.

```
$i='Utensils';

while($i!='0'){
  $sql="SELECT m.Categ_parent AS parent,t.Temp_parent AS parent, FROM table1 AS m,table2 AS t WHERE m.Categ_name='".$i."' OR t.Temp_name='".$i."' LIMIT 1";
  $result=mysqli_query($con,$sql);
  $row=mysqli_fetch_array($result);

  $i=$row['parent'];
  echo $i;
}
```

I'm not getting any result or error from this code

Comment: `if I search for 'Utensils', hoping to get`:-on what basis you are trying to find those categories? I am unable to find-out relation. Please elaborate how's you come to know that for `Utensils` categories `Cookware,Kitchen,House,Items` will come out?

Comment: the query is something like `select parent from table where name = 'Utensils'`. If there is a parent, then we perform the query again with the parent's name until there are no more parents

Comment: exactly as Brian said. that's what I'm trying to accomplish

Comment: It looks like you `House` has the parent `Item`, but there is no name called `Item`. It's actually `Items`, so we will never be able to select it from the table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For repeatedly accessing the same table, you might be better off using a stored procedure.

```
## Create a view so that we can work more easily with the tables 

create view items as select Categ_name as name, Categ_parent as parent from table1
  union (select Temp_name as name, Temp_parent as parent from table2);

name            parent
-------------------------
Item            0
House           Item
Car             Item
Kitchen         House
Living Room     House
Appliance       Living Room
Cookware        Kitchen
Utensils        Cookware

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS selectName;
CREATE PROCEDURE selectName(IN currentName VARCHAR(100))
BEGIN
  drop temporary table if exists tmp_results;
  create temporary table tmp_results (
    name varchar(100)
  );

  while (exists(select parent from items where name = currentName)) DO
    select parent into currentName from items where name = currentName;
    insert into tmp_results select currentName;
  END WHILE;

  select * from tmp_results;
END;
```

To use this procedure:

```
call selectName('Utensils');

Cookware
Kitchen
House
Item
0
```

PHP code to initialize database (run the statements only ONCE to create the view and stored procedure):

```
// create view
$mysqli->query("
  drop view if exists viewItems;
  create view viewItems as select Categ_name as name, Categ_parent as parent from table1
    union (select Temp_name as name, Temp_parent as parent from table2)";
");

// create stored procedure
$mysqli->query("
  DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS selectParents;
  CREATE PROCEDURE selectParents(IN currentName VARCHAR(100))
  BEGIN
    drop temporary table if exists tmp_results;
    create temporary table tmp_results (
      name varchar(100)
    );

    while (exists(select parent from viewItems where name = currentName)) DO
      select parent into currentName from viewItems where name = currentName;
      insert into tmp_results select currentName;
    END WHILE;

    select * from tmp_results;
  END"
);
```

PHP code to query

```
$name = mysqli_real_escape_string($name);
$results = $mysqli->query("CALL selectParents($name)");
```

Answer (score 0):

at first the SQL you wrote has an error which is the "," before "from ...".

I suggest using UNION instead of the current SQL command. The current command will mix two parent values and one of which may not be right.

Try the following solution, which works good on my computer:

```
$i='Utensils';


while($i!='0'){

$sql="(SELECT Categ_parent as parent from table1 WHERE Categ_name='".$i."')
        UNION
        (SELECT  Temp_parent as parent from table2 where Temp_name='".$i."')";


$result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);
if($result && mysqli_num_rows($result)){
    $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
    $i = $row["parent"];
}
else{
    $i = '0';
}

echo $i."<br>";
}
```

Comment: Yes, as pointed out by Brian, you should also pay attention to "item" and "items". Currently the code  won't reach "items", it will stop at "item".